# PIONEER 3DX for gazebo ,ros noetic

Tags: ros, gazebo-simu, slam

I am new to ROS. My goal is to implement a slam algorithm on a pioneer 3dx robot.  Where can I find a package for the PIONEER p3dx robot for ros noetic?  Any assistance is appreciated

I found a package for the aforementioned robot IN A git repository, but it was specifically for the ROS kinetic version.  Is it possible to utilize that package with the Noetic distro?  I tried and got several errors.  And how can I go about importing  it to gazebo?